# Secret file in Boomla open-source website

Tags: access-control, boomla

If I make a site open source, how can I save some data that should not be accessible by everyone? For example, I'd like to store some secret keys for APIs, while making the site available for others to fork and view.

One solution would be to maintain a copy of the website which is open source, and keep the live site closed source, but it is a bit cumbersome to always update the open-source one. And dangerous too, I might accidentally leak some sensitive keys.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you could make use of the API keys as currently there is no way to make HTTP requests from the Boomla server to the outside world. You could only use it in the client - but then it's not secret any more.

There is an *experimental* solution for this. You can create a branch named `db-fj9h9wdw`. You will be able to access it like you would access a DB (from any of the website's branches).

EDIT: I have created a demo: [secret-keys.boomla.net](http://secret-keys.boomla.net/)